# Dropbox for local development, Git for cloud

Tags: git, cloud, dropbox

I am asking this question because, while I have found related topics, most of which focus on using dropbox as a remote, I haven't found anything that specifically addresses this question:

> Is there anything hazardous about using dropbox as your local repo as a way to work seamlessly from/between multiple machines (eg. let's say I just made a fork, 
>   I make some changes on my desktop, then I want to continue work from my laptop without running any `$ git` commands), then having your remote elsewhere?
>
> Another way to say ask the question might be: is there a way to use all of the dropbox-connected machines as essentially one local development space ... the idea is that all of the machines on Dropbox would be essentially one machine for the purposes of development... I know that isn't the most clear way to ask the question, but I don't know how I can be more clear.

I just want to make sure that there won't be any conflicts between how the repository tracks changes, and the way they are synced via dropbox - more particularly, I am wondering if I make a commit, or stage file(s) on machine A (let's call these the "Operations"), and that update dropbox-syncs to machine B, will the Operations be reflected on machine B when the dropbox-sync is complete, does Git run something automatically to ensure the Operations are reflected (and if so, how frequently), or does Git require me to run something to ensure machine B reflects the Operations?

Answer (score -1):

Dropbox does offer you versioning but at a price and will only keep your edits over a period of 30 days, but in reality the two couldn't be more different.

Git + Github provide you with a place to push permanently versioned copies of your files (e.g. if your working on a project).

And Dropbox provides you with offsite backup of your files autonomously, so in the event of a system crash you can recover your files or if your at work you can share certain files to others without having to be at your computer.

I'd say Github is great for projects where you want to track all edits over time.

And Dropbox is there for when you want a backup of your files but don't want to carry around a portable drive everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really my question.